# Where are functions places when working with slots in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If component `A` is a parent to component `B`, where B has a slot. If `A` uses the slot with a button, where do you place the clickHandler, in `A` or in `B`?

Is both possible as long as you don't have both the same time? And if so, are there a best practice or does it depend on the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You place it in A.

Slots are just cues for Vue to 'put the template here'. `B` doesn't know that you're rendering a button in that template. `A` determines that it's a button being rendered, and thus determines what happens when that button is pressed.

Technically, you could check what is being rendered in the slot from Component B, and apply a clickHandler to the slot if it's a button, as it's all just a render function under the hood. But for the sake of 'where do I put my function', that's generally too complex and rarely useful.

Comment: Okay thanks, make sense you place the functions where you know about the (button) component. What does 'govern' means?

Comment: edited my answer to make it easier to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

The child component could expose data to the parent one using scoped slot, in the parent we put some element which could have some events that have handlers defined in the parent component.

Example :

**List**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
        <slot name="item" :item="item"></slot>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "list",
  props: ["items"],
};
</script>
```

parent :

```
<template>
  <list :items="items">
    <template #item="{ item }">
      <h3>{{ item }}</h3>
      <span @click="deleteItem(item)">delete</span>
    </template>
  </list>
</template>

<script>
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteItem(item) {
      console.log(item);
           this.items = this.items.filter((_item) => _item !== item);

    },
  },
  components: {
    List,
  },
};
</script>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-wildflower-vw0yj?file=/src/App.vue)